# How to model a workflow that has to return a result in one of the steps

Tags: cadence-workflow

Assuming I have a workflow:

1. Make an order
2. Process payment
3. Send API call to a 3rd party
4. Await for 3rd to make a call to my API via an exposed webhook

When I do:

`workflow.makeOrder();`

this will block, so I cannot get a result until step 1-4 is finished.

But if I do it async:

```
WorkflowExecution workflowExecution = WorkflowClient.start(workflow::makeOrder);

workflowExecution.getWorkflowId()
```

I cannot get the result of step 1. How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are currently (summer 2019) working on adding direct support for waiting synchronously for specific condition in the workflow code. We believe that in Q3 2019 it will be production ready.

Until then the simplest solution is to use query feature to return workflow state. See [HelloQuery](https://github.com/uber/cadence-java-samples/blob/master/src/main/java/com/uber/cadence/samples/hello/HelloQuery.java) for an example. The main drawback of this solution that the client has to poll the workflow until the state is updated to reflect the result of step 1.

If you need to ensure low latency of the response the recommended pattern to execute request/reply into workflow instance is:

- A process that initiates the request needs to expose an endpoint to complete the request.
- The synchronous request first sends a signal to the workflow. The signal arguments include a unique requestId as well as host and port of the client endpoint. Then it creates a `CompletableFuture` and inserts it into a map using requestId as a key. Then the requesting thread blocks on this `Future.get`.
- Upon receiving the signal the workflow performs all the necessary activities and state transitions. Then to reply the workflow invokes the *deliver result* local activity. This activity invokes the complete request endpoint using the host and port and passing requestId as one of the arguments.
- As the host and port specific to the process is used the request handler is executed in the same process that sent the original signal. Then it gets from the map the `CompletableFuture` that the original requested thread is blocked on and completes it with the result of the request received as another activity argument.
- The original thread is unblocked by receiving the request result and can continue its execution.

Comment: > reply the workflow invokes the deliver result local activity:

Is there some guide of how to do this?

Comment: Create local activity stub using Workflow.newLocalActivityStub and call an activity method on it.